# Mailinglists in Thunderbird with S/MIME

Tags: email, thunderbird, encryption, smime

I am looking for a solution to send encrypted mails to a (internal) mailinglist. To encrypt the mail to all the recipients, I need some way to tell Thunderbird what the recipients are.

I was hoping for a solution that works centralised, like via an LDAP server, but in the end, any will do.

For OpenPGP I'm currently distributing gpg.conf snippets with the correct "group" statements in it, but I lack a solution for S/MIME.

Comment: I suppose having the mailing-list server decrypt and reencrypt messages wouldn't be acceptable?

Comment: The mailserver in question is externally hosted, so I don't really want to decrypt there.